# ASP.NET Webform 4 issue with OS X VoiceOver on Safari

Tags: asp.net, macos, webforms, accessibility, voiceover

I'm not entirely sure if this is strictly on ASP.NET or could happen on other version, but it definitely is happening on ASP.NET4

Problem I'm having is when viewing a website built with ASP.NET4 WebForms (not MVC) with Safari and VoiceOver turned on, if you navigate to non-clickable element (like "p" tag or "h*" tag), VO announces that element as clickable, as long as they are inside of "form" tag (if you move the element out of "form" tag, VO will speak that element as regular "p" or "h*" element in inspector).

I've turned off all my JS so that only WebForms' JS loads and is still happening, so I'm fairly confident that this is caused by some JS coming from one of the ScriptResource.axd or WebResource.axd files.

example: http://www.kentico.com (sorry, can't post actual page due to NDA) and turn VO and navigate to any text/header element.

Did anyone ever had this problem and came up with solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without code it is hard to tell. View the source of the rendered page, see if a `tabindex` is set either in the code or va JS. If not, I'd recommend putting sample code in a JSFiddle.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with tabindex since those elements aren't tabbable, and does not have tabindex. I can't provide code, but exact same thing is happening on http://www.kentico.com . all code is viewable there.

Comment: well, looking at kentico, they have `<h2><a href="http://devnet.kentico.com/Articles">Articles</a></h2>`, so that's why VO announces the header is clickable. If you are talking about something different, please put the code in a JSFiddle or direct exactly where to look. I didnt mention this before since I assumed you viewed the source

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this only happens on VO with Safari.
If you look at http://www.kentico.com/Company and any "p" tag (eg. Intro text or "Our mission" text, "Our vision" text etc) which doesn't have link inside will still announce "... clickable" at end of text.